# how to make numbers and letters bottom even

Tags: css, laravel

I need a help to fix these line of code to make letters and numbers bottom even like vertical align etc but nothing works.

Please help me how to make numbers and letters even in header.

[Header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0pjz.png)

```
@extends('layout.layout')
@section('content')
        <h1> Welcome to Laravel 0123456789 </h1>
        <p> This is laravel web application first projects</p>
@endsection
```

Comment: you can change the font-family for your text. you can try sans-serif

Comment: where exactly i sould set the config for font family @Akash

Comment: @ Doni, I have provided a detailed explanation in the answers sections how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the css file in the `public` folder of your project. The path to your style sheet will be like: `public/css/styles.css`

Now you can use the `asset()` function to add the `css` into your template layout. Find the code below to do the same.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

or

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**In the `style.css` you can add the style as:**

`font-family: sans-serif;` for whichever element you want.

Comment: yes it work but i loss my previous setting for header1 and the setting for body

Comment: could i directly set the font-family in line of h1

Comment: @Akesh. you wont believe this. i add 

        <dt>Welcome to laravel 123456789</dt>

 and work without add css file custom, just add font-family as you mentioned in dt tag detail in prebuild css file. path public/css/app.css

Comment: @DoniMartGalumbangHutabarat, great it worked for you